# Search for a mix of numbers and chars with haystack (elasticsearch)

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using Django Haystack with Elasticsearch. I have a string field called 'code' in this type of format:

> 76-010

I would like to be able to search

> 76-

And get as a result

> 76-111
>
> 76-110
>
> 76-210
>
> ...
>
> and so on.

but I don't want to get these results:

> 11-760
>
> 11-076
>   ...

I already have a custom elastic search backend but I am not sure how should i indexing it to get the desired behavior.

```
class ConfigurableElasticBackend(ElasticsearchSearchBackend):

    def __init__(self, connection_alias, **connection_options):
        # see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636419/elasticsearch-edgengrams-and-numbers
        self.DEFAULT_SETTINGS['settings']['analysis']['analyzer']['edgengram_analyzer']['tokenizer'] = 'standard'
        self.DEFAULT_SETTINGS['settings']['analysis']['analyzer']['edgengram_analyzer']['filter'].append('lowercase')
        super(ConfigurableElasticBackend, self).__init__(connection_alias, **connection_options)
```

Comment: Have you seen [this article](https://wellfire.co/blog/custom-haystack-elasticsearch-backend/) because what it shows is pretty much all you need.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use an [`edgeNGram` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) in order to index every prefix of your `code` field. For instance, we would like `76-111` to be indexed as `7`, `76`, `76-`, `76-1`, `76-11` and `76-111`. That way you will find `766-11` by searching for any of its prefixes.

Note that [this article](https://wellfire.co/blog/custom-haystack-elasticsearch-backend) provides a full-fledge solution to your problem. The index settings for your case would look like this in Django code. You can then follow that article to wrap it up, but this should get you started.

```
class ConfigurableElasticBackend(ElasticsearchSearchBackend):

    DEFAULT_SETTINGS = {
      "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "edgengram_analyzer": {
              "tokenizer": "edgengram_tokenizer",
              "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "edgengram_tokenizer": {
              "type": "edgeNGram",
              "min_gram": "1",
              "max_gram": "25"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "mappings": {
        "your_type": {
          "properties": {
            "code": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "edgengram_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    def __init__(self, connection_alias, **connection_options):
        super(ConfigurableElasticBackend, self).__init__(connection_alias, **connection_options)

        self.conn = pyelasticsearch.ElasticSearch(connection_options['URL'], timeout=self.timeout)
        self.index_name = connection_options['INDEX_NAME']

        # create the index with the above settings
        self.conn.create_index(self.index_name, self.DEFAULT_SETTINGS)
```