# Can't find strings that aren't words in Django Haystick/Elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using Django Haystack with Elasticsearch as the backend for a real-time flight mapping service.

I have all my search indexes set up correctly, however, I'm having trouble returning results for searches that aren't full words (such as aviation callsigns, some of which take the style `N346IF`, others include full words such as in `Speedbird 500`). The `N346IF` style of query doesn't yield any results, whereas I can easily return results for the latter example.

I make my query as below:

```
queryResults = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=q) # where q is the query in string format
```

(note that in the past I used the `AutoQuery` queryset, but the documentation lists that this only tracks words, so I'm passing a raw string now).

I have my search index fields setup as `EdgeNgramField` with search templates.

I have a custom backend with the following index settings (as well as both the `snowball` analyzer and the `pattern` analyzer):

```
ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX_SETTINGS = {
    'settings': {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "lowercase",
                    "filter": ["haystack_ngram"]
                },
                "edgengram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "lowercase",
                    "filter": ["haystack_edgengram"]
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "haystack_ngram_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 4,
                    "max_gram": 15,
                },
                "haystack_edgengram_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 4,
                    "max_gram": 15,
                    "side": "front"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "haystack_ngram": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 4,
                    "max_gram": 15
                },
                "haystack_edgengram": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 4,
                    "max_gram": 15
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ELASTICSEARCH_DEFAULT_ANALYZER = "pattern"
```

My backend is configured as:

```
class ConfigurableElasticBackend(ElasticsearchSearchBackend):

    def __init__(self, connection_alias, **connection_options):
        super(ConfigurableElasticBackend, self).__init__(
                                connection_alias, **connection_options)
        user_settings = getattr(settings, 'ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX_SETTINGS')
        if user_settings:
            setattr(self, 'DEFAULT_SETTINGS', user_settings)

class ConfigurableElasticBackend(ElasticsearchSearchBackend):

    DEFAULT_ANALYZER = "pattern"

    def __init__(self, connection_alias, **connection_options):
        super(ConfigurableElasticBackend, self).__init__(
                                connection_alias, **connection_options)

        user_settings = getattr(settings, 'ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX_SETTINGS')
        user_analyzer = getattr(settings, 'ELASTICSEARCH_DEFAULT_ANALYZER')

        if user_settings:
            setattr(self, 'DEFAULT_SETTINGS', user_settings)
        if user_analyzer:
            setattr(self, 'DEFAULT_ANALYZER', user_analyzer)

    def build_schema(self, fields):
        content_field_name, mapping = super(ConfigurableElasticBackend,
                                              self).build_schema(fields)

        for field_name, field_class in fields.items():
            field_mapping = mapping[field_class.index_fieldname]

            if field_mapping['type'] == 'string' and field_class.indexed:
                if not hasattr(field_class, 'facet_for') and not \
                                  field_class.field_type in('ngram', 'edge_ngram'):
                    field_mapping['analyzer'] = self.DEFAULT_ANALYZER
            mapping.update({field_class.index_fieldname: field_mapping})
        return (content_field_name, mapping)

class ConfigurableElasticSearchEngine(ElasticsearchSearchEngine):
    backend = ConfigurableElasticBackend
```

What would be the correct setup in order to successfully yield results for search patterns that are both and/or `N346IF`-style strings?

Appreciate any input, apologies if this is similar to another question (could not find anything related to it).

---

*edit:* requested by solarissmoke, the schema for this model:

```
class FlightIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    flight = indexes.CharField(model_attr='flightID')
    callsign = indexes.CharField(model_attr='callsign')
    displayName = indexes.CharField(model_attr='displayName')
    session = indexes.CharField(model_attr='session')

    def prepare_session(self, obj):
        return obj.session.serverId

    def get_model(self):
        return Flight
```

Text is indexed as:

```
flight___{{ object.callsign }}___{{ object.displayName }}
```

Comment: I think we need to to see the schema for the fields that you are indexing. Please post the index definition.

Comment: @solarissmoke - just edited it. Please let me know if you think anything else is needed.

Comment: I am reasonably sure that I know what the issue is, but to help me confirm can you provide sample `Flight` data (`callsign`, `displayName`) that you can successfully search, and some that you can't, and the associated search query?

Comment: Sure thing!  A query that works:
`callsign` is `United 55`, `displayName` is `Tsuyoshi Hiroi` - with the query `United`, or `United 55`, the results are returned.

One that doesn't work:
`callsign` is `N133TC`, `displayName` is `Shahrul Nizam` and this query does not work by querying the callsign (where the query content is `N133TC`). However, this query works if the display name is used, `Shahrul` yields results).

Comment: Hmm, that is not what I expected. Can you confirm that in your `text` document the `___` are underscores and not spaces?

Comment: They are underscores yep. Wasn't sure if I was formatting this template correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving my own question - appreciate the input by solarissmoke as it has helped me track down what was causing this.

My answer is based on Greg Baker's answer on the question
[ElasticSearch: EdgeNgrams and Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636419/elasticsearch-edgengrams-and-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The issue appears to be related to the use of numeric values within the search text (in my case, the `N133TC` pattern). Note that I was using the `snowball` analyzer at first, before switching to `pattern` - none of these worked.

I adjusted my analyzer setting in `settings.py`:

```
"edgengram_analyzer": {
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "filter": ["haystack_edgengram"]
}
```

Thus changing the `tokenizer` value to `standard` from the original `lowercase` analyzer used.

I then set the default analyzer to be used in my backend to the `edgengram_analyzer` (also on `settings.py`):

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DEFAULT_ANALYZER = "edgengram_analyzer"
```

This does the trick! It still works as an EdgeNgram field should, but allows for my numeric values to be returned properly too.

I've also followed the advice in the answer by solarissmoke and removed all the underscores from my index files.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't fully explain the behaviour you are seeing, but I think the problem is with how you are indexing your data - specifically the `text` field (which is what gets searched when you filter on `content`).

Take the example data you provided, callsign `N133TC`, flight name `Shahrul Nizam`. The `text` document for this data becomes:

```
flight___N133TC___Shahrul Nizam
```

You have set this field as an `EdgeNgramField` (min 4 chars, max 15). Here are the ngrams that are generated when this document is indexed (I've ignored the lowercase filter for simplicity):

```
flig
fligh
flight
flight_
flight___
flight___N
flight___N1
flight___N13
flight___N133
flight___N133T
flight___N133TC
Niza
Nizam
```

Note that the tokenizer does not split on underscores. Now, if you search for `N133TC`, none of the above tokens will match. (I can't explain why `Shahrul` works... it shouldn't, unless I've missed something, or there are spaces at the start of that field).

If you changed your `text` document to:

```
flight N133TC Shahrul Nizam
```

Then the indexed tokens would be:

```
flig
flight
N133
N133T
N133TC
Shah
Shahr
Shahru
Shahrul
Niza
Nizam
```

Now, a search for `N133TC` should match.

Note also that the `flight___` string in your document generates a whole load of (most likely) useless tokens - unless this is deliberate you may be better off without it.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now, thanks for answering. I was unaware of how the tokeniser split. However, this doesn't do the trick, the `N133TC` callsign patterns are still not matching. Not sure if this has anything to do with the filters set... By the way, for reference, I had set the `flight__` prefix because the search handles different models, and I wanted to differentiate from them on the front end more easily. I'll switch and use another key to define these.

Comment: I suspect the issue is with how your data is being indexed but cannot see what it could be. You may need to use the Analysis API to see exactly what your analyzed data looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your help - much appreciated. Just a quick update, experimenting with this to find the right pattern; https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor